# Show that the smallest $k > 0$ such that $a$ divides $bk$ is $k = [a,b]/b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I show that the smallest $k > 0$ such that $a$ divides $bk$ is $k = [a,b]/b$ where $[a,b]$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$?

I tried looking under "unique factorization" but can't seem to come up with an answer.

Comment: srry i just learned latex and not used to typing in math problems. and yes k = [a,b]/b. and [] is common multiple of a and b

Comment: Updated/edited the question for you, davidf.

Comment: Do you know the relation $(a,b)[a,b]=ab$ (where $(a,b)$ is the GCD)?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Use the fact that if $a$ divides $bk$, then $bk$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a | bk$.
Let $c = \gcd(a, b)$,
$u = a/c$, and $v = b/c$,
so $\gcd(u, v) = 1$.

Then
$uc | cvk$
or
$u | vk$.
Since $\gcd(u, v) = 1$,
$u | k$.

The smallest such $k$ is,
obviously,
$k = u$,
so $k = u = a/\gcd(a, b)$.

Since $\gcd(a, b)lcm(a, b) = ab$,
$\gcd(a, b)= ab/lcm(a, b)$,
so
$k = a/(ab/lcm(a, b)) = lcm(a, b)/b$.